# How to match string of a certain pattern but exclude one specific pattern?

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I am new to python. I need to match column names of a pandas dataframe that is of the form :
`names_(one more additional word)`

But from this match, I need to skip one specific column name `names_info`

Assume the column names of the data are as following

```
"names_full" "names_first" "names_last" "names_attribute" "names_info" "address" "pin" "balance"
```

I manage to write this much in python:

```
colnames.str.contains(r"(names_)")
```

and it gives all columns with "names_" at the start. From this how to skip one particular case?
I am new to regex so please explain the logic as well if it is possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a negative lookahead which asserts that a certain terms does not come after `names_`, e.g.

```py
colnames.str.contains(r"names_(?!item$)")
```

This would match every column name except for `names_item` (though it *would* match `names_items`).

The regex pattern used here says to match:

```
names_     column name starts with "names_"
(?!item$)  what immediately follows is NOT "item"
```

Note that `names_items` is valid, as well as anything else containing `item` followed by one or more characters.

Comment: Hi thank you. May I know the logic for the ?,! and $ inside the '( )'?

Comment: Let me add something explicitly to my answer.

Comment: Hi what is the logic for this negative lookahead?

Comment: Sorry, the formatting was off.  Check the updated answer.

Comment: so `?! something` translates as `Not` 'something' ?